# Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"

Tags: android, scale, resolution

Randomly, my app crashs with an error:

```
Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"
```

I can't find documentation about this error. This error appears only on Android 11 on Nokia 2.4

Do you have ideas how I can resolve this ? or how I can debug this ?

Comment: Did you find out why it happens?

Comment: Having the same issue - did you solve it somehow?

Comment: Having the same issue, just getting errors in log:

03-06 12:28:05.297 29615 29615 E libc    : Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"
03-06 12:28:05.297 29615 29615 E libc    : Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"

Comment: I have the same error craches in some devices and in my app it is Related to SQLite  i don't why can't access SQLite database if you have any solution please let me know 

Answer (score 0):

i think the activity could not find your resource file and this error is on onCreate method on setContentView method.
check your resource file and connectivity with java file.i hope you will you will solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to backup SQLite database and demo app there is no problem but in my project craches with this error any idea?